# Matlab rfplot not working

Tags: matlab, function

I'm trying to plot the S-Parameters in a file .s4p using the RFtoolbox but it seams that the function that I need `rfplot` doesn't work.

I searched `which rfplot` to see if the function exsits, and it is, but it's empty. I opened and inside I have this line:

```
narginchk(1,Inf)
error(message('MATLAB:UndefinedFunctionTextInputArgumentsType','rfplot',class(varargin{1})))
```

I tried also with other versions of Matlab (I have R2017a) where I work, but everyone have this kind of function.
Do you know why? Al the other functions of RFtoolbox work perfectly. How can I solve it if this problem is not related to my version?

Comment: Do you own the toolbox? Is there any other function `rfplot`? Where do you find the one that exists? It should be in: `MATLABROOT\toolbox\shared\rflib\rfplot.m`

Comment: Yes I do. I have a lot of functions in path you're saying. All the functions to convert S matrices, Y, Z `s2s,s2y,s2z ecc`, sparameter folder and other few things. Now that I notice also rfparam is empty. The other stuff is inside `toolbox\rf\rf` I never notice this before because I never tried to plot S parameters. What I needed was just extract s2p or s4p files using `read` function

Comment: I asked also to other peoples with different versions and Antenna toolbox installed but they also have this kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

The function exist, and the code exist too, but its hidden. Its a MATLAB proprietary code and they do not want you to know the real code behind it, so you can not see it.